# Serialize ArrayList on device

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have developed an application in Android that downloads a lot of data through XML query REST.

The problem is that every time you start the app takes a long time to download the data.

My question is:

**How can I serialize these data, and update perhaps after a certain period of time?**

I want some advice or idea to implement, or even better an example. 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that one to serialize:
http://simple.sourceforge.net/

You can schedule an async task or a thread to update it.

Example for a thread that serializes data incl. a lock (only parts of the code)

```
static final Object sDataLock = new Object();
Serializer mSerializer;

class AsyncSave implements Runnable
{
    Object mSerialize;
    File mStorage;

    public AsyncSave(Object serialize, File storage)
    {
        mSerialize = serialize;
        mStorage = storage;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            synchronized (sDataLock) {
                // write
                mSerializer.write(mSerialize, mStorage);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
How can I serialize these data, and update perhaps after a certain period of time?
```

You can use thread/async task if you want certain data to be downloaded in **certain activity**. The async task/thread will be destroyed if the activity is destroyed.

If you want to download the data in **certain time**, use a `Service` instead. With a `service`, your data  will be downloaded even if the apps is closed. For example, you can set your apps to download certain data once a day.